# What is the best way to search a linked list for a particular value using the linux kernel?

Tags: c, linked-list, linux-kernel

I have created a linked list using the linux kernel, and I am trying to implement a way to search the linked list. My current implementation uses the "list_for_each_entry" macro to iterate over the list. Then, I check to see if I find the key. If it exist, then print out "key found" else print "key not found."

I have printed out the list so I know which keys are there and which are not, but when I try to find a key, my program just prints out "key not found." I am not exactly sure what I am doing wrong.

I have tried iterating over the linked list and checking to see if the key exist but it keeps saying "key not found" even though I know the key is in the linked list.

```
   #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "list.h"
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>

struct a_list {
    struct list_head list;
    int   key;
    int value;
};

static void append(struct a_list* ptr,int value, int key) {
    struct a_list* tmp;
    tmp = (struct a_list*)malloc(sizeof(struct a_list));

    if(!tmp) {
        perror("malloc");
        exit(1);
    }
    tmp->value = value;
    tmp->key = key;
    list_add_tail( &(tmp->list), &(ptr->list) );
}


static inline long
time_diff(struct timespec start, struct timespec end) {
    long diff_in_nano = (end.tv_sec - start.tv_sec) * (long) 1e9 + (end.tv_nsec - start.tv_nsec);
    return diff_in_nano;
}




int main() {
    struct a_list  blist;
    struct a_list* iter;
    struct timespec start, end;

    INIT_LIST_HEAD(&blist.list);

    /* add item to list */
    //Start time
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &start);
    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {

        append(&blist, i, rand());

    }
    //End time
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &end);

    // Display the time to add items to linked list
    printf("\033[1;34mTime taken to add items to linked list is: %ld us\033[0m\n", (long int)(time_diff(start, end)));

    /* iterates list and print key/value */
    //Start time
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &start);
    list_for_each_entry(iter,&blist.list,list) {
        printf("%d %d\n", iter->value, iter->key);
    }
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &end);
    printf("\033[1;34mTime taken to print the linked list is: %ld us\033[0m\n", (long int)(time_diff(start, end)));

    /* search the linked list */
    //Start time
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &start);
    list_for_each_entry(iter,&blist.list,list) {
        if (iter->key == 1) {
            printf("Key found \n");
        }
        else {
            printf("Key not found \n");
        }
    }
                  //End time
                  clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &end);

                  printf("\033[1;34mTime taken to search the linked list is: %ld us\033[0m\n", (long int)(time_diff(start, end)));



                  /* remove all items in the list */

                  //Start time
                  clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &start);

                  while( !list_empty(&blist.list) ) {
                      iter = list_entry(blist.list.next,struct a_list,list);
                      if (iter->key == 6) {
                          printf("key found \n");
                      }
                      list_del(&iter->list);
                      free(iter);
                  }
                  // End Time
                  clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &end);

                  // Display the time to delete 10 million items from the list
                  printf("\033[1;34mTime taken to remove all items from the list: %ld us\033[0m\n", (long int)(time_diff(start, end)));

                  return 0;
                  }
```

I will also include the contents of list.h below:

```
/**
 * 
 * I grub it from linux kernel source code and fix it for user space
 * program. Of course, this is a GPL licensed header file.
 *
 * Here is a recipe to cook list.h for user space program
 *
 * 1. copy list.h from linux/include/list.h
 * 2. remove 
 *     - #ifdef __KERNE__ and its #endif
 *     - all #include line
 *     - prefetch() and rcu related functions
 * 3. add macro offsetof() and container_of
 *
 * - kazutomo@mcs.anl.gov
 */
#ifndef _LINUX_LIST_H
#define _LINUX_LIST_H

/**
 * @name from other kernel headers
 */
/*@{*/

/**
 * Get offset of a member
 */
#define offsetof(TYPE, MEMBER) ((size_t) &((TYPE *)0)->MEMBER)

/**
 * Casts a member of a structure out to the containing structure
 * @param ptr        the pointer to the member.
 * @param type       the type of the container struct this is embedded in.
 * @param member     the name of the member within the struct.
 *
 */
#define container_of(ptr, type, member) ({                      \
        const typeof( ((type *)0)->member ) *__mptr = (ptr);    \
        (type *)( (char *)__mptr - offsetof(type,member) );})
/*@}*/


/*
 * These are non-NULL pointers that will result in page faults
 * under normal circumstances, used to verify that nobody uses
 * non-initialized list entries.
 */
#define LIST_POISON1  ((void *) 0x00100100)
#define LIST_POISON2  ((void *) 0x00200200)

/**
 * Simple doubly linked list implementation.
 *
 * Some of the internal functions ("__xxx") are useful when
 * manipulating whole lists rather than single entries, as
 * sometimes we already know the next/prev entries and we can
 * generate better code by using them directly rather than
 * using the generic single-entry routines.
 */
struct list_head {
    struct list_head *next, *prev;
};

#define LIST_HEAD_INIT(name) { &(name), &(name) }

#define LIST_HEAD(name) \
    struct list_head name = LIST_HEAD_INIT(name)

#define INIT_LIST_HEAD(ptr) do { \
    (ptr)->next = (ptr); (ptr)->prev = (ptr); \
} while (0)

/*
 * Insert a new entry between two known consecutive entries.
 *
 * This is only for internal list manipulation where we know
 * the prev/next entries already!
 */
static inline void __list_add(struct list_head *new,
                  struct list_head *prev,
                  struct list_head *next)
{
    next->prev = new;
    new->next = next;
    new->prev = prev;
    prev->next = new;
}

/**
 * list_add - add a new entry
 * @new: new entry to be added
 * @head: list head to add it after
 *
 * Insert a new entry after the specified head.
 * This is good for implementing stacks.
 */
static inline void list_add(struct list_head *new, struct list_head *head)
{
    __list_add(new, head, head->next);
}

/**
 * list_add_tail - add a new entry
 * @new: new entry to be added
 * @head: list head to add it before
 *
 * Insert a new entry before the specified head.
 * This is useful for implementing queues.
 */
static inline void list_add_tail(struct list_head *new, struct list_head *head)
{
    __list_add(new, head->prev, head);
}


/*
 * Delete a list entry by making the prev/next entries
 * point to each other.
 *
 * This is only for internal list manipulation where we know
 * the prev/next entries already!
 */
static inline void __list_del(struct list_head * prev, struct list_head * next)
{
    next->prev = prev;
    prev->next = next;
}

/**
 * list_del - deletes entry from list.
 * @entry: the element to delete from the list.
 * Note: list_empty on entry does not return true after this, the entry is
 * in an undefined state.
 */
static inline void list_del(struct list_head *entry)
{
    __list_del(entry->prev, entry->next);
    entry->next = LIST_POISON1;
    entry->prev = LIST_POISON2;
}



/**
 * list_del_init - deletes entry from list and reinitialize it.
 * @entry: the element to delete from the list.
 */
static inline void list_del_init(struct list_head *entry)
{
    __list_del(entry->prev, entry->next);
    INIT_LIST_HEAD(entry);
}

/**
 * list_move - delete from one list and add as another's head
 * @list: the entry to move
 * @head: the head that will precede our entry
 */
static inline void list_move(struct list_head *list, struct list_head *head)
{
        __list_del(list->prev, list->next);
        list_add(list, head);
}

/**
 * list_move_tail - delete from one list and add as another's tail
 * @list: the entry to move
 * @head: the head that will follow our entry
 */
static inline void list_move_tail(struct list_head *list,
                  struct list_head *head)
{
        __list_del(list->prev, list->next);
        list_add_tail(list, head);
}

/**
 * list_empty - tests whether a list is empty
 * @head: the list to test.
 */
static inline int list_empty(const struct list_head *head)
{
    return head->next == head;
}

static inline void __list_splice(struct list_head *list,
                 struct list_head *head)
{
    struct list_head *first = list->next;
    struct list_head *last = list->prev;
    struct list_head *at = head->next;

    first->prev = head;
    head->next = first;

    last->next = at;
    at->prev = last;
}

/**
 * list_splice - join two lists
 * @list: the new list to add.
 * @head: the place to add it in the first list.
 */
static inline void list_splice(struct list_head *list, struct list_head *head)
{
    if (!list_empty(list))
        __list_splice(list, head);
}

/**
 * list_splice_init - join two lists and reinitialise the emptied list.
 * @list: the new list to add.
 * @head: the place to add it in the first list.
 *
 * The list at @list is reinitialised
 */
static inline void list_splice_init(struct list_head *list,
                    struct list_head *head)
{
    if (!list_empty(list)) {
        __list_splice(list, head);
        INIT_LIST_HEAD(list);
    }
}

/**
 * list_entry - get the struct for this entry
 * @ptr:    the &struct list_head pointer.
 * @type:   the type of the struct this is embedded in.
 * @member: the name of the list_struct within the struct.
 */
#define list_entry(ptr, type, member) \
    container_of(ptr, type, member)

/**
 * list_for_each    -   iterate over a list
 * @pos:    the &struct list_head to use as a loop counter.
 * @head:   the head for your list.
 */

#define list_for_each(pos, head) \
  for (pos = (head)->next; pos != (head);   \
       pos = pos->next)

/**
 * __list_for_each  -   iterate over a list
 * @pos:    the &struct list_head to use as a loop counter.
 * @head:   the head for your list.
 *
 * This variant differs from list_for_each() in that it's the
 * simplest possible list iteration code, no prefetching is done.
 * Use this for code that knows the list to be very short (empty
 * or 1 entry) most of the time.
 */
#define __list_for_each(pos, head) \
    for (pos = (head)->next; pos != (head); pos = pos->next)

/**
 * list_for_each_prev   -   iterate over a list backwards
 * @pos:    the &struct list_head to use as a loop counter.
 * @head:   the head for your list.
 */
#define list_for_each_prev(pos, head) \
    for (pos = (head)->prev; prefetch(pos->prev), pos != (head); \
            pos = pos->prev)

/**
 * list_for_each_safe   -   iterate over a list safe against removal of list entry
 * @pos:    the &struct list_head to use as a loop counter.
 * @n:      another &struct list_head to use as temporary storage
 * @head:   the head for your list.
 */
#define list_for_each_safe(pos, n, head) \
    for (pos = (head)->next, n = pos->next; pos != (head); \
        pos = n, n = pos->next)

/**
 * list_for_each_entry  -   iterate over list of given type
 * @pos:    the type * to use as a loop counter.
 * @head:   the head for your list.
 * @member: the name of the list_struct within the struct.
 */
#define list_for_each_entry(pos, head, member)              \
    for (pos = list_entry((head)->next, typeof(*pos), member);  \
         &pos->member != (head);                    \
         pos = list_entry(pos->member.next, typeof(*pos), member))

/**
 * list_for_each_entry_reverse - iterate backwards over list of given type.
 * @pos:    the type * to use as a loop counter.
 * @head:   the head for your list.
 * @member: the name of the list_struct within the struct.
 */
#define list_for_each_entry_reverse(pos, head, member)          \
    for (pos = list_entry((head)->prev, typeof(*pos), member);  \
         &pos->member != (head);    \
         pos = list_entry(pos->member.prev, typeof(*pos), member))

/**
 * list_prepare_entry - prepare a pos entry for use as a start point in
 *          list_for_each_entry_continue
 * @pos:    the type * to use as a start point
 * @head:   the head of the list
 * @member: the name of the list_struct within the struct.
 */
#define list_prepare_entry(pos, head, member) \
    ((pos) ? : list_entry(head, typeof(*pos), member))

/**
 * list_for_each_entry_continue -   iterate over list of given type
 *          continuing after existing point
 * @pos:    the type * to use as a loop counter.
 * @head:   the head for your list.
 * @member: the name of the list_struct within the struct.
 */
#define list_for_each_entry_continue(pos, head, member)         \
    for (pos = list_entry(pos->member.next, typeof(*pos), member);  \
         &pos->member != (head);    \
         pos = list_entry(pos->member.next, typeof(*pos), member))

/**
 * list_for_each_entry_safe - iterate over list of given type safe against removal of list entry
 * @pos:    the type * to use as a loop counter.
 * @n:      another type * to use as temporary storage
 * @head:   the head for your list.
 * @member: the name of the list_struct within the struct.
 */
#define list_for_each_entry_safe(pos, n, head, member)          \
    for (pos = list_entry((head)->next, typeof(*pos), member),  \
        n = list_entry(pos->member.next, typeof(*pos), member); \
         &pos->member != (head);                    \
         pos = n, n = list_entry(n->member.next, typeof(*n), member))

/**
 * list_for_each_entry_safe_continue -  iterate over list of given type
 *          continuing after existing point safe against removal of list entry
 * @pos:    the type * to use as a loop counter.
 * @n:      another type * to use as temporary storage
 * @head:   the head for your list.
 * @member: the name of the list_struct within the struct.
 */
#define list_for_each_entry_safe_continue(pos, n, head, member)         \
    for (pos = list_entry(pos->member.next, typeof(*pos), member),      \
        n = list_entry(pos->member.next, typeof(*pos), member);     \
         &pos->member != (head);                        \
         pos = n, n = list_entry(n->member.next, typeof(*n), member))

/**
 * list_for_each_entry_safe_reverse - iterate backwards over list of given type safe against
 *                    removal of list entry
 * @pos:    the type * to use as a loop counter.
 * @n:      another type * to use as temporary storage
 * @head:   the head for your list.
 * @member: the name of the list_struct within the struct.
 */
#define list_for_each_entry_safe_reverse(pos, n, head, member)      \
    for (pos = list_entry((head)->prev, typeof(*pos), member),  \
        n = list_entry(pos->member.prev, typeof(*pos), member); \
         &pos->member != (head);                    \
         pos = n, n = list_entry(n->member.prev, typeof(*n), member))




/*
 * Double linked lists with a single pointer list head.
 * Mostly useful for hash tables where the two pointer list head is
 * too wasteful.
 * You lose the ability to access the tail in O(1).
 */

struct hlist_head {
    struct hlist_node *first;
};

struct hlist_node {
    struct hlist_node *next, **pprev;
};

#define HLIST_HEAD_INIT { .first = NULL }
#define HLIST_HEAD(name) struct hlist_head name = {  .first = NULL }
#define INIT_HLIST_HEAD(ptr) ((ptr)->first = NULL)
#define INIT_HLIST_NODE(ptr) ((ptr)->next = NULL, (ptr)->pprev = NULL)

static inline int hlist_unhashed(const struct hlist_node *h)
{
    return !h->pprev;
}

static inline int hlist_empty(const struct hlist_head *h)
{
    return !h->first;
}

static inline void __hlist_del(struct hlist_node *n)
{
    struct hlist_node *next = n->next;
    struct hlist_node **pprev = n->pprev;
    *pprev = next;
    if (next)
        next->pprev = pprev;
}

static inline void hlist_del(struct hlist_node *n)
{
    __hlist_del(n);
    n->next = LIST_POISON1;
    n->pprev = LIST_POISON2;
}


static inline void hlist_del_init(struct hlist_node *n)
{
    if (n->pprev)  {
        __hlist_del(n);
        INIT_HLIST_NODE(n);
    }
}

static inline void hlist_add_head(struct hlist_node *n, struct hlist_head *h)
{
    struct hlist_node *first = h->first;
    n->next = first;
    if (first)
        first->pprev = &n->next;
    h->first = n;
    n->pprev = &h->first;
}



/* next must be != NULL */
static inline void hlist_add_before(struct hlist_node *n,
                    struct hlist_node *next)
{
    n->pprev = next->pprev;
    n->next = next;
    next->pprev = &n->next;
    *(n->pprev) = n;
}

static inline void hlist_add_after(struct hlist_node *n,
                    struct hlist_node *next)
{
    next->next = n->next;
    n->next = next;
    next->pprev = &n->next;

    if(next->next)
        next->next->pprev  = &next->next;
}



#define hlist_entry(ptr, type, member) container_of(ptr,type,member)

#define hlist_for_each(pos, head) \
    for (pos = (head)->first; pos && ({ prefetch(pos->next); 1; }); \
         pos = pos->next)

#define hlist_for_each_safe(pos, n, head) \
    for (pos = (head)->first; pos && ({ n = pos->next; 1; }); \
         pos = n)

/**
 * hlist_for_each_entry - iterate over list of given type
 * @tpos:   the type * to use as a loop counter.
 * @pos:    the &struct hlist_node to use as a loop counter.
 * @head:   the head for your list.
 * @member: the name of the hlist_node within the struct.
 */
#define hlist_for_each_entry(tpos, pos, head, member)            \
    for (pos = (head)->first;                    \
         pos && ({ prefetch(pos->next); 1;}) &&          \
        ({ tpos = hlist_entry(pos, typeof(*tpos), member); 1;}); \
         pos = pos->next)

/**
 * hlist_for_each_entry_continue - iterate over a hlist continuing after existing point
 * @tpos:   the type * to use as a loop counter.
 * @pos:    the &struct hlist_node to use as a loop counter.
 * @member: the name of the hlist_node within the struct.
 */
#define hlist_for_each_entry_continue(tpos, pos, member)         \
    for (pos = (pos)->next;                      \
         pos && ({ prefetch(pos->next); 1;}) &&          \
        ({ tpos = hlist_entry(pos, typeof(*tpos), member); 1;}); \
         pos = pos->next)

/**
 * hlist_for_each_entry_from - iterate over a hlist continuing from existing point
 * @tpos:   the type * to use as a loop counter.
 * @pos:    the &struct hlist_node to use as a loop counter.
 * @member: the name of the hlist_node within the struct.
 */
#define hlist_for_each_entry_from(tpos, pos, member)             \
    for (; pos && ({ prefetch(pos->next); 1;}) &&            \
        ({ tpos = hlist_entry(pos, typeof(*tpos), member); 1;}); \
         pos = pos->next)

/**
 * hlist_for_each_entry_safe - iterate over list of given type safe against removal of list entry
 * @tpos:   the type * to use as a loop counter.
 * @pos:    the &struct hlist_node to use as a loop counter.
 * @n:      another &struct hlist_node to use as temporary storage
 * @head:   the head for your list.
 * @member: the name of the hlist_node within the struct.
 */
#define hlist_for_each_entry_safe(tpos, pos, n, head, member)        \
    for (pos = (head)->first;                    \
         pos && ({ n = pos->next; 1; }) &&               \
        ({ tpos = hlist_entry(pos, typeof(*tpos), member); 1;}); \
         pos = n)


#endif
```

Comment: What does this have to do with the Linux kernel?

Comment: I think they mean they got the implementation of the list from the kernel sources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code:

```
    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        append(&blist, i, rand());
    }
```

You are passing the parameters: `value=i` and `key=rand()` according to your function's signature:

`static void append(struct a_list* ptr,int value, int key)`

which does not insure that you will have key==1.

[man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/srand.3.html):

> The rand() function returns a pseudo-random integer in the range 0 to
>   RAND_MAX inclusive (i.e., the mathematical range [0, RAND_MAX]).

Comment: You are right! I was also using the wrong variable so that it the reason I could not find the key. Thank you!